# Detecting characters after symbols

Tags: java, symbols, character, integer

I'm trying to write a method going in two ways - if a character after the symbol $ is an integer, then I want to go to the second if statement and execute it. If a character after the symbol $ is a digit (or a letter), then I want to set that number to 16, and every time a new digit is used, I want to increment the setNumber by 1. Here's what I tried:

```
for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {

            int setNumber = 16;

            // 1st IF statement
            if (Character.isDigit(anyLines[i].charAt(the character after $)))
                        anyLines[i] = anyLines[i].replace("$","");
                        anyLines[i] = anyLines[i].replace(charAt(after zero),setNumber);
                        // Increment set number if a new digit is detected

                    }

            else {
                        continue;
                 }

            // 2nd IF statement
            if (anyLines[i].isInteger(anyLines[i].charAt(the character after $))) {
                anyLines[i] = anyLines[i].replace("$","");
                anyLines[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(131072  
+(Integer.parseInt(anyLines[i]))).substring(1,17);
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps some example input/output combinations? You realize that a digit *is* a integer, right? So what's the difference -- integers with more than one digit?

Comment: No, the difference is one is an integer and the other is a letter
If $1 is detected (it's an integer), then go to 2nd IF statement. If $A is detected (it's a letter), then go to 1st IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "af$Aklj$4r8$7jlkf$;a4$";
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (cs[i] == '$') {
            if (i + 1 < cs.length) {
                i++;
                if (Character.isDigit(cs[i])) {
                    System.out.print("digit after $: ");
                } else if (Character.isLetter(cs[i])) {
                    System.out.print("letter after $: ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("unhandled character after $: ");
                }
                System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(cs, i-1, 2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```